# Random black screens, black screens after log out, and random black flashes on boot. Please help

Tags: 12.04, boot, asus

Okay, so here's the deal. I had Ubuntu 12.10 on my Asus Zenbook UX32A. I heard that Ubuntu 12.04 LTS more reliable, and stable, so I decided to get that. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Now, when I boot the computer, first of all the ubuntu logo doesn't show up, it's just a purple screen. Then the screen flashes, and the logo shows with the purple screen. Then it flashes again, and takes me to the login screen where I hear the drums, and it flashes a few more times after that. I login, and it flashes again. Mind you, this happens every time I boot up my laptop, and it happens at probably the same times.

Not only that, if I try to logout, it logs me out, but the screen goes black, and I am not able to log back in. I have to force shutdown (hold power button) my laptop, and boot it up again. Today, I was trying to go into the display application in the system settings, once I clicked on it, my screen went black, and I had to boot up my laptop again. I also tried to change the resolution, and the screen went black.

Also, I can't right click, I have to double tap my touch pad like a Mac.

I really don't know what is going on. Ubuntu 12.10 on the same laptop worked relatively well. Why not 12.04 LTS which is supposed to be more stable? Please help, I need this laptop for a lot of things and can't afford it to be glitching out on me.

If you need any more information, I can tell you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to a command line with Ctrl-Alt-F1?  And if so can you login through the terminal?

If so you might be duplicating [Desktop login fails, terminal works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210480/desktop-login-fails-terminal-works)

Or
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-12-10-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Or 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen

Or possibly,
[12.04 installation started to black screen during boot today](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160169/12-04-installation-started-to-black-screen-during-boot-today)